# Saving custom data from inline forms (django admin)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am using `django-nested-inline` package with two levels.

```
class OrdersAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PointsInLine,]
    form = OrdersModelForm

class PointsInLine(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Points
    fk_name = 'order_id'
    inlines = [AddressesInLine]

class AddressesInLine(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Addresses
    fk_name = 'point'
    form = AddressModelForm
```

As you can see I also create a custom form for the last level (`AddressesInLine`) which looks like this:

```
class AddressModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['address'].widget = BoxSearchWidget()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Addresses
```

Again, I am overriding the field 'address' with a custom widget (which I will not include due to simplicity).

**Finally, the question is:** when I save, this custom field address is not saved, AND even when I tried to override save() method for the form, I can't see the value in any dictionary. So, **Am I missing something in the creation of the custom form?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling the `super(ModelForm, self).__init__` method, which is the `__init__` method of the `Form` class. Because of that, your class is constructed as a normal `Form` and not as a `ModelForm`.

You should be calling `super(AddressModelForm, self).__init__` instead. Remember: the first argument to `super` is the child type for which you need to get a method of the parent type. You can find more information about `super` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).